# How do I add random times to to_date datatype?

Tags: sql, oracle

The following statements will be executed.

```
select current_timestamp + dbms_random.value(40, 59) minute from dual;
```

The statement I want doesn't work.

`to_date('2021-01-05:08:50:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd:hh24:mi:ss') + dbms_random.value(40, 59) minute;`

I am getting the error `<analytic clause>, '@', KEEP or WITHIN expected, got 'minute'` and

I am wondering how to solve this.

Comment: That doesn't look like an Oracle error; if it is actually coming from Oracle what is the ORA- error number and full message? If not which client or application is generating it? (And are you sure it's coming from that expression; and that you're using an Oracle database - and which version?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is `minute` in your context?

If it is an *alias*, everything is OK:

```
SQL> select to_date('2021-01-05:08:50:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd:hh24:mi:ss') +
  2    dbms_random.value(40, 59) minute
  3  from dual;

MINUTE
-------------------
20.02.2021 02:09:25

SQL>
```

If it is an *expression*, then remove "minute" and use

```
to_date('2021-01-05:08:50:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd:hh24:mi:ss') + dbms_random.value(40, 59);
```

only.

P.S. As Wernfried commented, the "minutes" part is missing, so either use his suggestion (with the interval) or this:

```
dbms_random.value(40, 59) * 1 / (24*60)
                          -------------
```

Comment: This will all add a random number of days rather than minutes. Should be `+ dbms_random.value(40, 59) / 24` or `+ dbms_random.value(40, 59) * INTERVAL '1' MINUTE`