# How can I set hours and minutes of date with oracle sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I set hours and minutes of date with oracle sql?

Below is my code.

```
while venter < sysdate
                loop
                    venter := venter + 1;
                    venter := venter - v1;
                    v1 := dbms_random.value(0, 30) / (24 * 60);
                    venter := venter + v1;

                    vexit := vexit + 1;
                    vexit := vexit - v2;
                    v2 := dbms_random.value(0, 20) / (24 * 60);
                    vexit := vexit + v2;
                    if mod(to_char(venter, 'd'), 7) + 1 in (1, 2) then --weekend
                        continue;
                    end if;
                    insert into testattend values ​​(vseq, venter, vexit, 'normal', null, vclassSeq);

                    vseq := vseq + 1;
                    -- dbms_output.PUT_LINE(vseq);
-- dbms_output.PUT_LINE(venter);
                end loop;
```

Minutes are added as random values ​​to the values ​​stored in the venter.
If this loop continues, the values ​​will accumulate and become abnormal data.

So, I added minus and plus using v1.
However, the data is output abnormally.

I wonder if there is a way to leave the venter's day as it is and set only the hour, minute, and second values ​​of 8:45:00 when running the loop.

best regard

Comment: What is 'abnormal' (or, indeed, normal)? What `venter` value are you starting with, and what do you want to happen; where does 08:45 fit in? (And it [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67784622/266304) related?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wonder if there is a way to leave the venter's day as it is and set only the hour, minute, and second values ​​of 8:45:00 when running the loop.

You don't need a PL/SQL loop and multiple `INSERT` statements; you can do it all in a single SQL statement:

```sql
INSERT INTO testatend
WITH calendar ( vseq, venter, vexit ) AS (
  SELECT 1,
         DATE '2021-05-01' + INTERVAL '08:45:00' HOUR TO SECOND,
         DATE '2021-05-01' + INTERVAL '17:15:00' HOUR TO SECOND
  FROM   DUAL
UNION ALL
  SELECT vseq + 1,
         venter + CASE TRUNC(venter) - TRUNC(venter, 'IW')
                  WHEN 4 THEN INTERVAL '3' DAY -- Previous day is Friday
                  WHEN 5 THEN INTERVAL '2' DAY -- Previous day is Saturday
                         ELSE INTERVAL '1' DAY -- Prev. day is Sunday to Thursday
                  END,
         vexit  + CASE TRUNC(venter) - TRUNC(venter, 'IW')
                  WHEN 4 THEN INTERVAL '3' DAY -- Previous day is Friday
                  WHEN 5 THEN INTERVAL '2' DAY -- Previous day is Saturday
                         ELSE INTERVAL '1' DAY -- Prev. day is Sunday to Thursday
                  END
  FROM   calendar
  WHERE  venter + INTERVAL '1' DAY < SYSDATE
)
SELECT vseq,
       venter - NUMTODSINTERVAL( DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0, 30), 'MINUTE'),
       vexit  - NUMTODSINTERVAL( DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0, 30), 'MINUTE'),
       'normal',
       null,
       123 -- vClassSeq
FROM   calendar
```

*(Note: If you want fixed times then do not subtract `NUMTODSINTERVAL( DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0, 30), 'MINUTE')` in the final step.)*

Which, for an example table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE testatend (
  id        NUMBER,
  time_in   DATE,
  time_out  DATE,
  type      VARCHAR2(20),
  something NUMBER,
  class_id  NUMBER
);
```

Then inserts 23 rows which may have the values:

> | ID | TIME_IN | TIME_OUT | TYPE | SOMETHING | CLASS_ID |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 2021-05-01 08:31:46 | 2021-05-01 17:01:16 | normal |  | 123 |
> | 2 | 2021-05-03 08:37:28 | 2021-05-03 16:48:27 | normal |  | 123 |
> | 3 | 2021-05-04 08:21:48 | 2021-05-04 16:49:06 | normal |  | 123 |
> | 4 | 2021-05-05 08:16:39 | 2021-05-05 17:12:19 | normal |  | 123 |
> | 5 | 2021-05-06 08:41:02 | 2021-05-06 16:49:22 | normal |  | 123 |
> | 6 | 2021-05-07 08:42:28 | 2021-05-07 17:09:07 | normal |  | 123 |
> | 7 | 2021-05-10 08:35:11 | 2021-05-10 16:46:37 | normal |  | 123 |
> | 8 | 2021-05-11 08:31:00 | 2021-05-11 16:56:35 | normal |  | 123 |
> | 9 | 2021-05-12 08:43:20 | 2021-05-12 17:05:23 | normal |  | 123 |
> | 10 | 2021-05-13 08:21:07 | 2021-05-13 16:50:53 | normal |  | 123 |
> | 11 | 2021-05-14 08:34:12 | 2021-05-14 17:01:06 | normal |  | 123 |
> | 12 | 2021-05-17 08:31:46 | 2021-05-17 16:45:04 | normal |  | 123 |
> | 13 | 2021-05-18 08:39:08 | 2021-05-18 17:04:08 | normal |  | 123 |
> | 14 | 2021-05-19 08:24:34 | 2021-05-19 16:53:57 | normal |  | 123 |
> | 15 | 2021-05-20 08:39:33 | 2021-05-20 17:12:05 | normal |  | 123 |
> | 16 | 2021-05-21 08:24:42 | 2021-05-21 16:46:23 | normal |  | 123 |
> | 17 | 2021-05-24 08:40:35 | 2021-05-24 16:52:41 | normal |  | 123 |
> | 18 | 2021-05-25 08:41:08 | 2021-05-25 16:47:41 | normal |  | 123 |
> | 19 | 2021-05-26 08:27:00 | 2021-05-26 17:04:04 | normal |  | 123 |
> | 20 | 2021-05-27 08:40:47 | 2021-05-27 17:00:28 | normal |  | 123 |
> | 21 | 2021-05-28 08:40:38 | 2021-05-28 16:52:54 | normal |  | 123 |
> | 22 | 2021-05-31 08:22:53 | 2021-05-31 16:45:51 | normal |  | 123 |
> | 23 | 2021-06-01 08:26:23 | 2021-06-01 17:14:09 | normal |  | 123 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=dfae021587cdc56ed40c0feda5efd0fe)*

Comment: Great fast answer !